# Multiple Layers add in MapMyIndia

Tags: mapmyindia-api

How can we add multiple layers in Map? Also, we need to remove particular kml layers from map.

I have added multiple layers adding one by one

```
kmlLayer=new MapmyIndia.kml(map,kml, {fitBounds:true,async: true});
```

kml url pass dynamically in this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple layer as kml with different kml url or data.

To Remove use : kmlLayer.remove(); or in case of array kmlLayer[0].remove()